# Can we index in Solr single core data from two different formats i.e. from csv and text?

Tags: solr, full-text-search, solrj

I have data in two formates CSV and TEXT.

1) CSV file contains metadata. i.e. ModifyScore, Size, fileName etc.

2) actual text are in Text folders having files like a.txt, b.txt etc.

Please is it possible to index such data in Solr in a single core through DIH or another possible way?

Answer (score 0):

According to your use case I would proceed with a custom indexing app.
Apparently you want to build your Solr document fetching some field from the CSV and some other field( the content) from the TXT .

Using Java for example, it is going to be quite simple :
You can use SolrJ, fetch the data from the CSV and TXT, build each Solr Document and then index it.

I would use the DIH if I can move the data in a DB ( even 2 tables are fine, as DIH supports joins).
Out of the box, you may be interested in using the script [1] transformer.
Using it in combination with your different data sources could work.
You need to play a little bit with it as it's not a direct solution to your problem.

[1] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-TheScriptTransformer

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention a couple more possibilities:

1. Use DIH to index txt files into collectionA, and use /update handler to ingest csv directly into collectionB, then use [Streaming Expressions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Streaming+Expressions) to merge both into a third collection that is the one you want to keep. The main advantage is everything is in Solr, no external code.
2. Use DIH to index files (or /update to index csv) and write a [Update Request Processor](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Update+Request+Processors) that will intercept docs before they are indexed, that looks up the info from the other source, and adds it to the doc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for resourceful help @Persimmonium. I like the first answer, I have already index the text files in Core A and csv file in Core B, both the cores have same unique key field. Please is it possible to merge these cores using streaming expressions.

Comment: I think all the pieces are there, you just have to build up your expressions (that might be quite complex)

Comment: can I use Streaming Expressions for solr cores? @ Persimmonium

Comment: if you mean if you can use it in standalone solr, then no, you need solrcloud

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible for information and code, how to index data from multiple  heterogeneous data sources see [why the tikaEntityProcesor does not index the Text field in the following data-config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420735/why-the-tikaentityprocesor-does-not-index-the-text-field-in-the-following-data-c)